# Writing list of sublists into file without brackets and separated with ";"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new here (and also in python) so tell me if I do something wrong.
I have a little (I think) problem:
I have a list of sublists where all variables (x) are float:

```
tab=[[x11,x12,x13],[x21,x22,x23]]
```

And I wanto to write to the *txt file without brackets [] and separated by ";" like this:

x11;x12;x13

x21;x22;x23

I tried to do it like this: but i have no idea what should I do next.

```
tab=[[x11,x12,x13],[x21,x22,x23]]
result=open("result.txt","w")
result.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), tab)))
result.close()
```

A lot of thanks for everyone who will try to help me.

Comment: You forgot to join the rows, `"\n".join(map(";".join,  tab))`

Comment: Side-note: `map(lambda x: str(x), tab)` is a silly/slow way to do `map(str, tab)`. If you need a `lambda` to use `map`, just use a list comprehension or generator expression instead; they're more Pythonic, and avoiding the function call will make them faster anyway. Someone new to Python should not use `map` or `filter` at all, because they're largely the wrong solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for this:

```
import csv

with open("result.txt", "wb") as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(tab)
```

The [`csv.writer.writerows()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) takes a list of lists, and converts floating point values to strings for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
result.write("\n".join([';'.join([str(x) for x in item]) for item in tab]))
```

Or, little simpler:

```
result.write("\n".join([';'.join(map(str, item)) for item in tab]))
```